# subclipse- Unable to load default SVN Client while adding repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using eclipse kepler, I am trying to install subclipse. I have installed subclipse using "install new software" option specifying the ": http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x" as the url.
Installation went smooth, however, when I try to add new repository I am getting error "Unable to load default SVN Client". Can you please tell me what I am missing here?. I am using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to download the SVNKit:

[image]

2. Make sure that SVNKit is the selected SVN interface:

[image]